# ReactJS materialUI how to change the color of textarea on focus

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to change the inbuilt color of TextField in material UI. I have done it with CSS. I referred to the CSS injection order in material UI, and also to some of the stackoverflow answers and got up with a solution. But I even tried this in some other different way. I am not sure why it did not work, can anyone explain me the difference in working with below two code snippets ?

The js code for `TextField` is:

```js
 <TextField
          id="standard-name"
          label="Name"
          value={this.state.name}
          onChange={this.handleChange('name')}
          margin="normal"
          fullWidth
          InputLabelProps={{
            classes: {
              root: classes.main,
              focused: classes.focusedLabel
            }
          }}
          InputProps={{
           classes: {
            root: classes.underline
           }
          }}
        />
```

And the CSS (that worked):

```js
const styles = theme => ({
  main: {
    "&$focusedLabel": {
      color: "cyan"
    },
  },
  focusedLabel: {},
  underline: {
    "&:after": {
      borderBottom: `2px solid cyan`
    }
  },
});
```

I made some changes and used CSS property `:focus` with it. But Now the color is not changing on focusing the input.

The updated CSS code is:

```js
const styles = theme => ({
  main: {
    "&:focus": {
      color: "cyan"
    },
  },
  underline: {
    "&:after": {
      borderBottom: `2px solid cyan`
    }
  },
});
```

I tried this out with `:hover` property, it worked. I am not sure why the property `:focus` not working ??

Can anyone explain me, where did I go wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work to use the ":focus" pseudo-class because the label is not the element that has focus. The `focused` class is applied to the `InputLabel` when the corresponding **input** has focus.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But even if I try the same with the focused class alike "&:focused", it is not working ?. But if I try "&:hover" it is working (i.e on hovering the input ??

Comment: You already showed in your question how to correctly use the focused class: `"&$focusedLabel"`. `"&:hover"` works when hovering over the label; I do not see it doing anything to the label when hovering over the input.

Comment: As you said `focused` is the prop there. I tried this out https://dpaste.de/5Ftp. Instead of giving color inside `"&$focusedLabel"` I gave it in the `focusedLabel` object itself. But I am not sure why this is not working ?